# In Electron, why is it only possible to set frame rate in offscreen rendering?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, electron, chromium

[Electron methods that are only possible to use with offscreen rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwCD7.jpg)

This picture was taken from the Electron documentation.
My question is why is it only possible to use theses methods in offscreen mode?

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. (And where relevant -- as in this case -- include a link to where the text came from.) Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 1):

Because as it says in an answer to [this issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/34693) requesting the ability to use that API for on-screen windows:

> The frame rate of on-screen windows matches the screen refresh rate.